# What's the difference between const member function and const-ref member function

Tags: c++

For the following code:

```
class C
{
public:
    void fun() const {};
    void fun() const & {};
};
```

I know that this is illegal, since we cannot overload with `const` and `const &`. However, my question is: we already have `const` member function in the old standard, why did we need to introduce the `const &` member function? Are there any semantic differences between a `const` member function and a `const-ref` member function?

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between const member function and const-ref member function

Lvalue ref qualified function cannot be called on rvalue instance arguments (unless the function is also const qualified). Unqualified member functions can be.

Comment: Don't understand. I tried to call both version with rvalue instance, it seems all versions work: https://godbolt.org/z/9rG3ox and https://godbolt.org/z/rahrze

Comment: Just like you can call const qualified member function through non-const objects, you can call const-ref qualified function through rvalue "objects". You can't however call an rvalue-reference (void f() &&) qualified member function using an lvalue. The lvalue-ref qualified version can be useful if you want to have two versions of the same function: one that would be called when the object is a lvalue, and one that is called when the object is an rvalue

Comment: @WeiLi Sure, but try modifying a non-mutable member variable in const qualified function. That is not possible, while it is possible in a non-const lvalue ref qualified function. Likewise, try calling a const qualified non-lvalue ref qualified function on an rvalue. You'll find that it is possible.